# How do I display the whole line of text?

Tags: shell-script

Example of my information:

```
Fruit,Quantity:Cost,Sold
Red Apple,10,1,5
Green Apple,10,2,20
Orange,20,1,10
```

Here's my code:

```
if      [ "$fruit != $blank" ] && [ "$quantity" == "$blank" ]; then
        cut -d\, -f1 information.txt | grep $fruit
elif    [ "$quantity != $blank" ] && [ "$fruit" == "$blank" ]; then
        cut -d\, -f2 information.txt | grep $quantity
```

My code will only display the intended search, so if you key in "Apple", it will only display "Red Apple" and "Green Apple" but not the quantity, how do I make it to display all the information. Same as quantity, if you key in "20", it will only display "20".

Comment: Look back at @jimmij's answer to your other question.

Comment: tried it, doesn't work, it will display everything, let's say i key in 20 under fruit, it will display the orange as well @mikeserv

Comment: I'm talking about his mention of your quotes.

Comment: I understand, what he showed is having 2 conditions in 1 search, what i'm trying to solve is, what if the user entered something else in the search, like example of what i mention earlier, entering the quantity instead of the fruit he wants to search. @mikeserv

Comment: Apart from quotes, you intentionally `cut` off only first field and ask why it display only that. Remove `cut` and try again.

Comment: I intentionally added cut because i need the search function to only limit to the first section, then display the result as a whole as the final output. @jimmij

Comment: So use `grep ^$fruit` to grep only at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I have tried that, it will work, but if you enter "10" into $fruit, it will still display as if the user was entering "Apple". @jimmij

Comment: @Zac No, it will not.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, at least for now, i edited  the information above, how do I search for, let's say SOLD, 10, without it displaying the QUANTITY result. @jimmij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cut` is effectively removing the information you are looking for from the input you feed to `grep`. Use just

```
grep "^[^,]*$fruit[^,]*" information.txt
```

instead of

```
cut -d\, -f1 information.txt | grep $fruit
```

and

```
grep "^[^,]*,$quantity$" information.txt
```

instead of

```
cut -d\, -f2 information.txt | grep $quantity
```

to filter the lines you are interested in. The regexp:

- `^` starts the matching at the beginning of line;
- `[^,]*` matches any string not containing a comma (`,`);
- `$fruit` matches the string contained in the `fruit` environment variable;
- the other `[^,]*` should be obvious at this point.

Once you add more fields into your data, you might need to modify the regexps - in that case any tutorial on those will come in handy, syntax is in the `grep(1)` man page (i.e. use: `man grep`).

If you insist on using `cut` and your input is sorted, you can put the information back using `join` (for the first case):

```
inf=information.txt
cut -d, -f1 $inf | grep "$fruit" | sort -u | join -t, -j 1 - $inf
```

- `cut` outputs the first field (`-f1`) of file whose name is contained in the environment variable `inf`, where fields are delimited with a comma (`-d,`);
- `grep` see above;
- `sort` sorts and removes duplicates (`-u`);
- `join` joins lines from its standard input (the `-` in next to the last argument) with the contents of the file given as the last argument. It uses a comma as a field separator (`-t,`) and joins lines whose first fields are identical (`-j 1`).

The requirement to have sorted data comes from `join` (at least the one in the coreutils package) - I haven't checked how big problems you could run into with unsorted data.

Comment: I'm not sure what to use, and i saw an example displaying selected data, so i was giving it a shot, is there other commands to use, i re did my information, and what if there are repetitive values in the information, like the above, how do i go about just searching in the category I want to search and displaying the result as a whole.

Comment: use the `grep` I provided. Using "some examples" without understanding how they work won't get you very far. (Adding short explanation for the `grep` command, so that it doesn't become just another magic incantation. :))

Comment: sorry, i just started this language a week back, have no basic knowledge of it at all, only did basic c#, do you mind explaining how your code works ?

Comment: Thanks, but you said that if i insist on using cut, are there other options to use to give the output i need.

Comment: Should be a bit more helpful now. If you are a complete beginner, stating that in your question might be useful - it is often expected that people have at least some basic knowledge on which can be built - and the answers reflect that (as you have noticed).

Comment: thanks once again, i will try to improve with all of the suggestions given, can i comment here again if i still need help ? Or will i have to re-post new questions again ?

Comment: Sorry, still can't get it to work, nothing displays out this time, and in this command grep "^[^,]*,$quantity$" where do i put the location of the information.txt because i have tried to put it in different places, but none if it works.

Comment: As with most other basic UNIX commands, you either pipe the input to standard input of the command (`command_producing_data | grep ...`) or you give filenames at the end of the command line (`grep "...regexp..." file1 file2 file3 ...`). You do need to read (and understand) some introduction to UNIX shell scripting, without it you'll be bumping into trees around a clear path - an hour now is going to save you a day tomorrow (I'm glad to help, but might easily become a suboptimal use of both of ours time).